# Await Promise in Electron ipcRenderer.invoke via context bridge

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am having a hard time to apply the [Invoke Method](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args) from the Electron Documentation via Context Bridge to my project.

From `renderer.js` I need to trigger an async function in `main.js` and wait for the response in `renderer.js`.

My code below successfully triggers an action in `main.js`. However, the response in `renderer.js` is **`undefined`**.

I tried several different modifications but it keeps getting worse. Please point out what I'm doing wrong here!

`preload.js`

```
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    "api", {

        doInvoke: (channel, func) => {
            let validChannels = ["some-channel"];
            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, data).then((result) => {return result})
            }
        },
    }
);
```

`renderer.js`

```
$(document).on('keyup','input', async function(e){
    let response = await window.api.doInvoke(channel='some-channel', data='test-string')
    console.log(response) //--> logs undefined
})
```

`main.js`

```
ipcMain.handle('some-channel', async (event, data) => {
  const result = await doSomeWork(data)
  return result
})

async function doSomeWork(data){
  console.log(data)  //--> logs 'test-string'
  return data + 's'
}
```

Comment: "*`window.api.doInvoke(channel='some-channel', data='test-string')`*" - uh, js does not have named arguments. That'll try to assign to global variables, and throw in strict mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst there are a number of minor issues that can be optimised, the main issue is the failure to correctly return the result from your `preload.js` script to your `index.html` (`renderer.js`) file.

Below is a minimum reproducible example.

---

Your `main.js` file is just about perfect. That said, instead if assigning `doSomeWork` to `result` and then returning it, just return it directly.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
// Import required electron modules
const electronApp = require('electron').app;
const electronBrowserWindow = require('electron').BrowserWindow;
const electronIpcMain = require('electron').ipcMain;

// Import required Node modules
const nodePath = require('path');

// Prevent garbage collection
let window;

function createWindow() {
    const window = new electronBrowserWindow({
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        show: false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: false,
            contextIsolation: true,
            sandbox: true,
            preload: nodePath.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    });

    window.loadFile(nodePath.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
        .then(() => { window.show(); });

    return window;
}

electronApp.on('ready', () => {
    window = createWindow();
});

electronApp.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
        electronApp.quit();
    }
});

electronApp.on('activate', () => {
    if (electronBrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
        createWindow();
    }
});

// ---

electronIpcMain.handle('some-channel', async (event, data) => {
    return await doSomeWork(data);
})

async function doSomeWork(data) {
    console.log(data) //--> logs 'test-string'
    return data + 's'
}
```

---

Your `preload.js` script was just about right. Instead of returning from within the `.then` statement, just return the `invoke` function. This is where the problem was.

`preload.js` (main process)

```js
// Import the necessary Electron modules
const contextBridge = require('electron').contextBridge;
const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;

// Exposed protected methods in the render process
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld(
    'api', {
        // From render to main and back again
        doInvoke: (channel, data) => {
            let validChannels = ["some-channel"];

            if (validChannels.includes(channel)) {
                return ipcRenderer.invoke('some-channel', data);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

---

Regarding your `index.html` file, as [ipcRenderer.invoke(channel, ...args)](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/ipc-renderer#ipcrendererinvokechannel-args) returns a promise there is no need to use `async/await`. Instead, just use a `.then` statement to process the promised response.

Additionally, don't assign the `channel` and `data` variables within the function definition. Instead, the parameters can just be the values.

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <label for="input">Input: </label>
        <input type="text" id="input" autofocus>
    </body>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('keyup', () => {
            window.api.doInvoke('some-channel', 'test-string')
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log(response); //--> logs 'test-strings'
                });
        })
    </script>
</html>
```